# Vmware EULA - Essentials and vSphere Standard same site

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, licensing

Can a company run a vSphere Essentials cluster and maintain a vSphere Standard cluster at the same time and still be in license compliance in the VMware EULA?

No requirement for all hosts to be managed by one vCenter server.

Comment: VMware is a fairly large company...I'm betting they have a way to field licensing questions. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Why not?

If you pay for them and aren't managing via the same Virtual Center, there's no problem.